# React.js Reading values from another function and using them to export to txt in another function

Tags: reactjs, function, txt

was trying to read values (points) from another function. Console logging in the upper functions writes them correctly. But when i console log in the exportFile function I'm getting undefined when i download the txt. What could be the problem. This is a jsx file format. New to react so I really don't understand what should i change.

The point is to read the x, y, width, height and write them to txt file

```
const normalizePredictions = (predictions, imgSize) => {
if (!predictions || !imgSize || !imageRef) return predictions || [];
return predictions.map((prediction) => {
  const { bbox } = prediction;
  const oldX = bbox[0];
  const oldY = bbox[1];
  const oldWidth = bbox[2];
  const oldHeight = bbox[3];

  const imgWidth = imageRef.current.width;
  const imgHeight = imageRef.current.height;

  const x = (oldX * imgWidth) / imgSize.width;
  const y = (oldY * imgHeight) / imgSize.height;
  const width = (oldWidth * imgWidth) / imgSize.width;
  const height = (oldHeight * imgHeight) / imgSize.height;

  console.log(x, y, width, height);

  return { ...prediction, bbox: [x, y, width, height]};
  });
 };

const exportFile = (x, y, width, height) => {
    let points = (x, y, width, height);
    console.log(x, y, width, height);
  
    var blob = new Blob([points], { type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8" });
  saveAs(blob, "testfile1.txt");
  };
```

Comment: Your function signatures are different and I can't see how/where they're invoked. In normalized normalizePredictions x, y, width, height are calculated internally; in exportFile they're passed in the invocation. For me/someone to help you, you're going to need to provide more clarity around invocation

Comment: invocation you mean in the () at the start? So what i understand, i return them in the  normalizePrediction, It means I can use them in any other function (Probably). So them i write exportFile = (x, y, width, height) so i can use them inside this function. So the point is that i want them to be used in this exportFile function so that i can write them to the txt file and download it